# Deserializing json string with array of array with Json.NET

Tags: c#, arrays, json, json.net

```
string json = @"{
'symbol':'XX',
'column_names":["Date","Open","High","Low","Close","Volume"],
'data':[
['2014-01-02',25.78,25.82,25.47,25.79,31843697.0],
['2013-12-31',25.81,26.04,25.77,25.96,22809682.0]]}";

public class DailyData
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public List<OneDay> data { get; set; }
}

public class OneDay
{
     public DateTime date { get; set; }
     public double open { get; set; }
     public double high { get; set; }
     public double low { get; set; }
     public double close { get; set; }
     public double volume { get; set; }
}

DailyData dd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DailyData>(json);
```

This is my json string and class I'm trying to deserialize it into with `Json.net`. It will work if I change  public `List<OneDay> data { get; set; }` to `public List<object> data { get; set; }`. But in this case I have to do more steps further. Is there a neat solution to deserialize it in one go?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you have to use the `JsonConverter` class to tell the deserializer how to map an array of values to the `OneDay` class.

**Example:**

```
void Main()
{
    string json = @"{
                        'symbol':'XX',
                        'column_names':['Date','Open','High','Low','Close','Volume'],
                        'data':[
                            ['2014-01-02',25.78,25.82,25.47,25.79,31843697.0],
                            ['2013-12-31',25.81,26.04,25.77,25.96,22809682.0]
                                ]
                    }";

    DailyData dd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DailyData>(json);
    dd.Dump();
}

class OneDayJsonConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        OneDay obj = new OneDay();
        obj.date = reader.ReadAsDateTime() ?? DateTime.MinValue;
        obj.open = (double)(reader.ReadAsDecimal() ?? 0);
        obj.high = (double)(reader.ReadAsDecimal()?? 0);
        obj.low = (double)(reader.ReadAsDecimal() ?? 0);
        obj.close = (double)(reader.ReadAsDecimal() ?? 0);
        obj.volume = (double)(reader.ReadAsDecimal() ?? 0);
        reader.Read(); 
        return obj;
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public class DailyData
{
    public string symbol { get; set; }
    public List<OneDay> data { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(OneDayJsonConverter))]
public class OneDay
{
    public DateTime date { get; set; }
    public double open { get; set; }
    public double high { get; set; }
    public double low { get; set; }
    public double close { get; set; }
    public double volume { get; set; }
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Dump() is an extension method provided by LINQPad which is used to provide the output you see in the screenshot above. You should give LINQPad a try.

Comment: Thank Dominic, I will research it